# Changing coordinates of a choice box

Tags: java

I have some code for an applet I made.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends Applet {
     Color clr;

     public void paint(Graphics g) {
         clr=new Color(0,68,255);
          setBackground(clr);
         g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
        g.drawString("Select between the numbers.",40,10);
     }

     public void init() {
         char x='\n';
         Choice c = new Choice();
         c.add("1");
         c.add("2");
         c.add("3");
         add(c);
     }
}
```

I want to set coordinates of the `Choice c` but when I give coordinates, it says illegal coordinates or something like that... Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Two questions should be posted as two separate questions

Comment: Alright... thanks for warning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manually position a component, you have to set the layout of the applet to `null` and then you can use `setLocation()`.

For example, using the small program I made before for you other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952191/how-do-i-use-if-condition-with-a-choice-box), you can use this code.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends Applet {
    Color clr;
    Choice c = new Choice();

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        clr=new Color(0,68,255);
        setBackground(clr);
        g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
        g.drawString("Select between the numbers.",40,10);
    }

    public void init(){
        char x='\n';
        setLayout(null);
        c.add("1");
        c.add("2");
        c.add("3");
        c.addItemListener(new CustomItemListener());
        c.setLocation(100,100);
        add(c);
    }

    class CustomItemListener implements ItemListener
    {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getSource() == c) {
                if(c.getSelectedItem().equals("1")) {
                    System.out.println("1 is selected in Choice selector c");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces something which looks like this.

[image: Applet with cmd open on top to show output]

Comment: @bmw Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You should use windowBuilder. Here is a tutorial on how to install it. Thank me later.!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeswfZz4IW0

Comment: thank you but you know I want to write everyting by myself :)