# How do I use if condition with a choice box?

Tags: java

I am really stuck in this step...

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Main extends Applet{
     Color clr;
     public void paint(Graphics g){
         clr=new Color(0,68,255);
          setBackground(clr);
         g.setColor(new Color(255,255,255));
        g.drawString("Select between the numbers.",40,10);
     }
     public void init(){
         char x='\n';
         Choice c = new Choice();
         c.add("1");
         c.add("2");
         c.add("3");
         add(c);
     }
}
```

What I want to do is, when user choose something from the box, it will launch the concerned class I tried something but it didn't work. What can I do?

Thanks for the any help.

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible as per comments by OP "I have absolutely no idea but I solved it somehow..." below under an Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Item listener to do what you want.

For example, in your code, it might look something like

```
public void init(){
    char x='\n';
    Choice c = new Choice();
    c.add("1");
    c.add("2");
    c.add("3");
    c.addItemListener(new CustomItemListener());
    add(c);
}

class CustomItemListener implements ItemListener
{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        //Your code to do something - ie
        if(e.getSource() == c) {
            if(c.getSelectedItem().equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("1 is selected in Choice selector c");
                // or to launch a class
                new YourClassYouWantToLauch();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much that will probably solve the problem :)

Comment: I think it isn't working because nothing shows up on the console...  "1 is selected in Choice selector c" is not showing up.

Comment: Try removing the `if(e.getSource() == c) {` statement and just having `if(c.getSelectedItem().equals("1")) {`

Comment: now these are showing up: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Viraj.Ana$CustomItemListener.itemStateChanged(Ana.java:36)
 at java.awt.Choice.processItemEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Choice.processEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: thank you for helping by the way :)

Comment: I will fix the problem but I have to go out for 2 hours. If you haven't fixed it by then I shall update code. Sorry

Comment: I have absolutely no idea but I solved it somehow... Thank you so much anyway you gave me the idea at least :)

Comment: @bmw Great. Glad you fixed it. Sorry I wasn't of more help